# Which Stack Exchange community is most appropriate for asking about war statistics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked this question on Politics.SE, but I apparently chose badly:
[Do rural dwellers have a higher probability of survival than city dwellers in times of war?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/63067/36717)

> It seems logical that the probability of survival would be higher in
> rural areas.
>
> 1. More reliable access to food.
> 2. Lower probability of being targeted.
>
> However, I cannot find any hard
> data to either confirm or deny this hypothesis.

Where can I ask that question?

Comment: I think you got good advice in a comment here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63067/do-rural-dwellers-have-a-higher-probability-of-survival-than-city-dwellers-in-ti#comment252532_63067 though I don't see it easily molded into a Worldbuilding question unless you're looking to design a world in which one population or another faces more of the cost of war.

Comment: With regards to [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/362173/5), if you have a separate feature request for a "find your community" button, you should post a completely different question. Also, yep! You can ask for [tag:site-recommendation]s here!

Comment: There's also a general guide across all SE sites: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." So, if you can't identify *why* you are asking a question (what's your goal?) you'll have a hard time writing a useful one (referring to your comment there that you "just need an answer" - better if you can explain *why* you need an answer).

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps taking a best guess and then asking for suggestions when we guess badly is an appropriate strategy. The The site-recommendation tag is a good suggestion too. Thanks. Will create a separate feature request question.

Answer (score 4):

*In general,* if you are wondering about "war statistics" for previous wars, [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) might work, but it seems that you're asking about [your specific question which was closed on Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/63067/30766).

[The first comment on your question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63067/do-rural-dwellers-have-a-higher-probability-of-survival-than-city-dwellers-in-ti#comment252532_63067) says:

> "This isn't a question about politics. You might be able to ask for historical data on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/), or you might be able to formulate an on-topic [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) question. If you've seen someone argue this publicly, you might be able to ask if there's evidence for it on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)."

Are you asking where your question would fit, apart from those three sites which were already suggested? That's already a wide range of options and I don't think there's other SE sites that would be very enthusiastic about this question.

If you do ask on History.SE, I would recommend to "polish" the question up a bit. Maybe use bullets to format your two points, and be more specific about what you want, in the question body too (not just the title). Your question says "I cannot find any hard data to either confirm or deny this hypothesis", whereas a question ending in a question mark is sometimes better received.

One of your comments says:

> "I just need answer to my question. "

But I would recommend not to write things like this if you try your question on another site. This type of statement sometimes rubs people the wrong way, and when you're asking a question, it's best if you do as much as you can (within the rules of SE) to give your question the best opportunity to get good answers.

Comment: I guess also urbanisation and death tolls would be very time/civilisation/war dependant. A narrower scope might be useful

Answer (score 2):

You might try the Open Data site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ if you want an answer based on analysing datasets. They do have a tag for historical and one for demographics.

Disclaimer: I am not signed up to that stack so have no idea what its users' customs and practices are.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly a site recommendation - but looking at the question, I suspect it depends - and narrowing the scope of the question to specific timeframes and conflicts might be useful.

Your answer would be very different between say medieval and early classical western wars, where troops foraged for food and marched across the country side, historic/epic era wars in India, which supposedly sometimes took place in designated battlefields, or modern/mechanised wars. which tend to focus on urban areas. Many modern conflicts also involve irregular forces and tactics that may result in, or encourage collateral damage.

Even in modern eras, in some wars, tactics similar to scorched earth tactics might be in place, or farmers affected by things like air scattered mines, or mis-placed ordinance.

As per our [help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

The 'answer' to your question even scoped to a single war would pretty much probably a thesis level bit of writing, with deep research. As it is, it would probably fill a bookshelf.

I'd also add - in the technical communities, questions we encourage people to ask is "What have I tried so far?" and "What am I trying to do?"

What's your research shown you? What's the *real* question you're trying to answer?

In its current state the question is impossible to answer.